# Main.js for App.vue calling an API to populate values

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Need to do an api call either as part of the (app.vue) main.js file or before it.  I am not using node js, I am trying to keep this site static.  Is there a way to pull (2) values from an API that are needed inside the (app.vue) main.js file?  I want to pull these at runtime time NOT in the build process.

I have tried to do this in a plugin, but the plugin seems to be scoped to vue and not to the main.js file so I am not sure how to get the values from the plugin.

I want to call the main site url, when the main.js file executes I want it to make an API call to populate (2) variables that need to be set inside Vue.use code below.

The values I need to populate are client/tenant

```
Vue.use(Adal, {
// This config gets passed along to Adal, so all settings available to adal can be used here.
  config: {
    // 'common' (multi-tenant gateway) or Azure AD Tenant ID
    tenant: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

    // Application ID
    client: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

    // Host URI
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080',

    cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
  }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you make an AJAX call to get the data you need at runtime?

Comment: If you can run ajax from the main.js I could do that.  Have an example?

Comment: Honestly I don't use vue so I don't know, but [this link](https://stackabuse.com/sending-ajax-requests-in-vue-js/) may help.